# How to process a page event prior to Forms Authentication Redirects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a website that uses basic ASP.Net forms authentication.  In the web.config file we specify specific access rules for individual pages and directories.  Everything works great.

However, now I have some new requirements.  My domain contains many different sites setup among different subdomains.  I have two DNS subdomains that map to this application.  One is aaa.mysite.com and the other is www.mysite.com.  If a particular web request is received from subdomain aaa.mysite.com for a page protected by FormsAuthentication, before the FormsAuthentication logic is handled (the user would be re-directed to the login page), I want to execute some code first.  This code would essentially try to read a cookie from a third subdomain, say zzz.mysite.com, and if does not exist, Response.Redirect to a login page in the zzz.mysite.com application.

I tried handling this via a base class that any of my Forms Authentication protected pages could inherit from, and then calling the special code in the Page_PreInit function.  However, FormsAuthentication handles the redirect to the Login page even before the PreInit function is called.

Does anyone know a good way to handle this case?  If Page_PreInit won't work, where can I put code so that it executes prior to the FormsAuthentication redirect does, but where I also have access to which page it is (and what class it inherits from, so I can see if it inherits from System.Web.UI.Page or if it inherits from my special BasePage).

Any ideas?  I think I could use the Globals Application_BeginRequest, but then this would be called for every single request, which doesn't seem like a very good idea.

I can't be the first person who has needed a way to handle an event prior to the FormsAuthentication, so please if you could give me some additional ideas I would be very appreciative!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cookie has been written to `zzz.example.com` then a site on `www.example.com` cannot read it - the way to share cookies across subdomains is to write them to `.example.com`.

This can be configured in forms authentication using the `domain` attribute on the [forms element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) in the web.config:

```
<forms [...]
   domain=".example.com">
```

Note the leading period in the domain names.

**Edit to respond to comment**

You should probably be hooking into the [PostAuthenticateRequest event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthenticaterequest.aspx) - this is fired after the users identity (or lack of) is established, and you could register a [custom HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858.aspx) to receive this event.

**Edit to show workings**

Ok, I've just tested the following setup:

A web application project, with the following directory structure:

```
/Default.aspx                    -- Simple aspx page.
/Login.aspx                      -- Simple aspx page, with a Login control.
/web.config                      -- Main application config.
/Classes/CheckingAuthenticate.cs -- HttpModule, configured in root.
/Restricted/Default.aspx         -- Simple asp page.
/Restricted/web.config           -- Config file for authorization
```

So, the root web.config sets up Forms authentication, using a standard ASP.NET membership provider, and sets `/Login.aspx` as the login page. I have also registered a custom HttpModule in there:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="CheckingAuthenticate" 
       type="TempWebApp.Classes.CheckingAuthenticate"/>
  [...]
</httpModules>
```

The web.config in `/Restricted/` denies access to anonymous users (this could equally be done in a `<location>` element in the root):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I then have the following code in my http module:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace TempWebApp.Classes {
  public class CheckingAuthenticate : IHttpModule {

    public void Dispose() {
        //clean-up code here.
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
      context.PostAuthenticateRequest += OnPostAuthenticate;
    }

    public void OnPostAuthenticate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      var app = sender as HttpApplication;

      if (!UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(app.Request.Path,
                                                            app.User,
                                                            "GET")){
        //Code here to read cookies, redirect user etc.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will fire after the user has been authenticated, but before ASP.NET attempts to authorize the user, so you get a chance to check the access yourself and redirect instead. I've been able to hit breakpoints on that quite happily. I didn't get to see the AuthorizeRequest or PostAuthorizeRequest events if the user didn't have access to those pages.

Comment: Yes, this is true, the cookie is written to .example.com, so that all the subdomains can access it.  The question remains then if the cookie does not exist yet, how can I Response.Redirect them to another domain prior to the Forms Authentication redirect taking place?

Comment: I can definitely write code in my Global.asax.cs file for this event, but doesn't that fire after the user has been authenticated?  I want to do my redirect prior to the user being redirected by the forms Authentication to the login page and asked to login.  However, as in my comment to Hank, I need a way to test whether or not the page the user is trying to access is protected by the forms authentication first.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the  AuthenticateRequest event. See the [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28VS.80%29.aspx). Don't worry about it happening on every request, a lot of stuff does that.

Comment: If I used this method, what method do I call to check if the current Page being accessed requires Forms Authentication based on the rules in the web.config?

Comment: I found UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal, but this method requires a valid IPrincipal object, and at this point in the life cycle HttpContext.Current.User is null.  I don't know the user at this point, because I want to redirect prior to finding out.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check the linked page. The next event is PostAuthenticateRequest. You probably can use the AuthorizeRequest as well.